# how can I hide underline from <Item> in native base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I work with native-base in react native and I have a problem .
how can I hide underline from `<Item>` in native base?
please help me

Comment: Can you please share more code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change color for input border in `theme/variables` [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/variables/commonColor.js#L186)

OR customize underlined textbox for you in `theme/components` [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/components/Item.js)

Answer (score 16):

You can also set `borderColor: 'transparent'` and give it as style to the Item